Calculate the deflection of a fixed supported beam
I am having a lot of trouble with the below question. Im not really sure how to calculate the deflection of the x coordinate, how do i go about completing this question?
Any help would be appreciated thank you so much! :)
"Suppose we have a uniform beam that is 2.94 metres long has a flexural rigidity of 33772 Nm2.
Find the deflection of the beam in millimetres if the beam is under a load of f(x)=8.05(x+1.0762)(3.34−x)N/m and is supported with fixed supports at both ends. Fill out the table below with your answers.
x-coordinate
x=0.24
x=0.62
x=1.62 "

Wasn't this asked yesterday?

Does this table help?

P = f(x)=8.05(x+1.0762)(3.34−x)N/m; x=0.24, 0.62, 1.62 "
For the given x-coordinates, watch out where "x" is measured from - the free end or the fixed end.

This answer is not correct. It provides the deflection for a concentrated load applied on an arbitrary position. The original question considers a variable distributed load.
